# How to go through each link within a div and update the text based on criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following has been generated with a `asp:Repeater` control (hence the repeated ID):

```
<span id="lblLocation1">
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=87">400 Westchester Avenue</a>, 
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=89">56 Theall Road</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1606">73 Market Street</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1947">98 Huguenot Street</a>
</span>
<br />
<br />

<span id="lblLocation1">
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=87">400 Westchester Avenue</a>, 
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=89">56 Theall Road</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1606">73 Market Street</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1947">98 Huguenot Street</a>
</span>
<br />
<br />

<span id="lblLocation1">
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=87">400 Westchester Avenue</a>, 
    <a href="/office.aspx?id=89">56 Theall Road</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1606">73 Market Street</a>, 
    <a title="" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1947">98 Huguenot Street</a>
</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s7LkoqdL/2/

The result should be to go through each anchor within the `lblLocation1` span and check to see if it meets the criteria and update the link text.

What is happening is, it displays multiple entries at the same time with the variable.

How can I modify the query so it goes through each link within the span and updates based on if it meets the criteria and then goes to the next link and then the next and so forth...

Note: The more `span` entries there are the more it multiplies per link.

Comment: you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition just get rid of id and make it class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite your whole fiddle as it is  mess.

You can use `$('.pS span a').text(function)` to deal with instances. The first argument of callback is the element index and the second is the existing text. Just `return` the new text based on conditions

```
$('.pS span a').text(function (index, oldText) {    

     if (oldText.indexOf("Theall") >-1) {
        return oldText + vCityState[4]; 
     }else if (oldText.indexOf("98") >-1) {
        return oldText + vCityState[2]; 
     }      
});
```

I would suggest you create an array of objects that you can loop through within each instance to simplify manually creating all the `if` conditions:

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7LkoqdL/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: This should be a guide. Let me try it out. Thanks. I don't need a `each` function?

Comment: No, when using the function as argument it will loop them all internally

Comment: I got the hold of it @charlietfl. Thank you. I have it working. Thank you the short and quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle has JS error, try use `var vAChild = $( this ).text();` and `indexOf` for searching matched  text. see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7LkoqdL/7/)

Comment: This didn't solve my issue unfortunately. It was working at some but not others.